# Laravel contextual information logging doesn't work when specifying logging channel

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-10

When using contextual information if logging in Laravel v10 (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#contextual-information), the contextual information doesn't get merged when specifying the channel name.

e.g.: This works fine:

```php
Log::info(
   'User {user} created Thing {id}', 
   [
      'user' => auth()->user()->id,
      'id' => $thing->id
   ]
);
```

...produces:

```
[2024-01-31 08:44:23] local.INFO: User 1 created Thing 3 {"user":1,"id":3}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```php
Log::channel('mychannel')->info(
   'User {user} created Thing {id}',
   [
      'user' => auth()->user()->id,
      'id' => $thing->id
   ]
);
```

...as it produces:

```
[2024-01-31 08:36:15] local.INFO: User {user} created Thing {id} {"user":1,"id":2}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not covered in the documentation - in order to get this to work, you need to include the `'replace_placeholders' => true` directive in the logging config, e.g.:

config/logging.php:

```php
<?php
...
        'mychannel' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/mychannel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the merging of contextual information with your log message when using a specific channel, you can manually merge the context into the log message using the withContext() method.

```
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

$log = new Logger('my_channel');
$log->pushHandler((new StreamHandler('path/to/log/file'))->withContext(['user_id' => 123]));

$log->info('User {user} created Thing {id}', ['user' => auth()->user()->id, 'id' => $thing->id]);
```

To merge contextual information into log messages when using a specific channel in Laravel, you can follow the approach you mentioned earlier, where you manually merge the context into the log message

```
Log::channel('mychannel')->info(
    'User {user} created Thing {id}',
    array_merge(
        ['user' => auth()->user()->id, 'id' => $thing->id],
        Log::getLogger()->getHandlers()[0]->getExtra()
    )
);
```

Comment: "_using the withContext() method_" Where are you using that method in your code?

Comment: sorry @brombeer that was typo mistake you try this